# Intersecting a circle and a geodataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, intersection, shapely

I have created a circle which I am trying to intersect with a geodataframe as follows:

```
circle_gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry= [circle])


joinCircle = gpd.sjoin(left_df=circle_gdf, right_df=transactions,  how="left", predicate="intersects")
```

My aim is to find all transactions that intersects with the circle. The result gives me a geodataframe which contains only the geometry of the circle which is:

```
POLYGON ((33.58429 -7.62047, 33.58426 -7.62053...
```

I get no right geometries at all. I am sure there is intersection somewhere. Is there another method of intersecting and checking the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a crs when you create the circle df:

```
circle_gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[circle], crs=????)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing a left join (`how="left"`), so (only) the geometry of the `left_df`, so the circle, is retained in the output as explained in the documentation of the `how` parameter [here](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin.html#geopandas.sjoin).

If I understand you correctly, you want to know the geometries of the transactions that intersect the circle. So you need to do an inner join (`how="inner"`) with the transactions as `left_df` and the circle as `right_df` to get this result:

```
circle_gdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[circle])

transactions_in_circle = gpd.sjoin(
    left_df=transactions,
    right_df=circle_gdf,
    how="inner",
    predicate="intersects",
)
```

Comment: i already tried `inner` join but the output is empty dataframe